# xamarin mac Controller.designer.cs file not being filled

Tags: xcode, macos, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I am currently developing a cocoa app using Xamarin mac. to do this i open the story board in the XCode interface builder add my controllers and UI then run the application with visual studio mac. the problem I'm running into is even on a simple project if i open the story board add a controller and a button the controller's .designer.cs file never contains the button or any other control. through debugging ive confirmed its using the correct controller and the UI is display correctly but that intermediary designer.cs file only contains the default code

```
[Register ("ReportController")]
partial class ReportController
{
    
    void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()  
    {
    }   
}
```

I'm unable to build XCode as it is just generating a dummy project and fails with undefined symbol: _main but visual studio is able to build fine and reflects any UI changes made in XCode.
Thank you all for your time I fear I'm missing something really basic, I've used the windows version of the interface builder for IOS before and never ran into this issue however for that it was built into visual studio so perhaps there is a step I'm missing.

Comment: Hi, whether save the edit after adding controls? And you could share the version of VS for Mac and Xamarin iOS.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT currently im running 8.8 build 2913 for visual studio however i have tried the current preview build as well and was having the problem on that. this shows up weather i just save in XCode or then open it in visual studio edit the file and save again.

Comment: Okey, thanks for sharing. I will check that, if good news will update here later.

Comment: Hi, I have checked the version of Visual Studio, and it works in my local site.

Comment: huh thats strange ?  to confirm you have it working for a cocoa app being developed on MAC OS right ? i can get xamarin.IOS to work fine just not cocoa/xamarin.mac

Comment: Yes, I have updated an answer. You could have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You could see that I have added a **Hello** button in the storyboard, and if you want to see the Button in **.designer.cs**, you need to connect this `Button` to the **Controller.h** in Xcode. More can refer to **[Adding an Outlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/get-started/hello-mac#adding-an-outlet)**.

[image]

Then **Hello** button will show in **.designer.cs** automatically：

[image]

Finally, Screenshot at runtime.

[image]